# Custom pagination search in post type with meta key

Tags: pagination

I am new to WordPress and try to set pagination based on a custom query, by using Query found the result from the meta key custom field and product result.

But the issue comes here in pagination query result is based on $wp_query.

How can I set the value of custom query into the $wp_query

```
    //$s='GPO2'
    //query for meta search 
    // searching  the result from the meta field 
     $q1 = array(
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'product_sku',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field( $s ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '  
    product_color_0_color',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($s),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $q1 );

    // search the result from main table         

     $q2 = &new WP_Query("s=$s&showposts=-1&post_type=products&fields=ids"); 

    //here by using these queries  found the unique ids

    if(!empty($loop->posts) && !empty($q2->posts))
    {
      $unique = array_unique( array_merge( $loop->posts, $q2->posts ) );  
    }
    elseif(!empty($loop->posts) && empty($q2->posts))
    {

      $unique=$loop->posts;
    }else{
      $unique=$q2->posts;
    }



    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { // 'page' is used instead of 'paged' on Static Front Page
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }


    $posts= array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'post__in' => $unique,
          'paged' => $paged,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10
    );

    $allsearch= &new WP_Query( $posts );
    the_posts_pagination( array(
            'format'             => 'page/%#%/?s='.$msgSearch.'',
            'prev_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Previous page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>',
                    'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Next page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . '</span>',
                    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyseventeen' ) . ' </span>',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $allsearch->max_num_pages,
            'rewrite' => false
                ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `the_posts_pagination` probably relies on the main query. You will need to "hack" the query global var or simple replace the main query (if you're not using it afterwards).

So replacing the main query:

```
//$allsearch= &new WP_Query( $posts );
query_posts($posts);
```

Or replacing the main query vary

```
$allsearch= &new WP_Query( $posts );
$backup = $GLOBALS['wp_query'];
$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $allsearch;

the_posts_pagination();

$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $backup;
```

Also, I've noted you used a variable named $posts. I've already faced some issues using global variable names with queries, so I do not recommend using a variable named $posts

Comment: thanks for your reply , i  have already done this part and it update the $GLOBALS['wp_query']  and  pagination  number  showing in correct way  but some  pagination link showing page not found .I think it still  using main query

Comment: Strange. The next paginated page is calling the same query? Also, try re-save the permalink settings just to make sure it's not a missing rule.

Comment: ya it was also strange  for  me , At the last i have solved the error  :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution.